# VS2010 Error in Recycling IIS Application Pool: Not Found

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, iis, application-pool

I'm making a Sharepoint visual web part in Visual Studio 2010 and it seems like out of nowhere I started receiving the error: "Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Not found"

In the output for my program it says which application pool it's looking for and I know it exists because it shows up in IIS Manager

Now I've already tried resetting IIS, along with recycling the application pool manually in IIS Manager.

Really I'm sort of at the end of my rope and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the user that has run Visual Studio doesn't have rights to Recycle the IIS application pool.

To solve this, run visual studio with some user who has rights (shift + right button -> run as different user) or try to follow this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062%28v=bts.70%29.aspx

Comment: I'm an admin on the box VS is running on and I'm running VS as an admin too.

Comment: In fact, this is happening in one of our projects. We have an admin user who can deploy without problems but others users (as mine) need to open VS with "run as different user". I have found those articles, I will hive a better look and try tomorrow at office, but if you manage to solve it before please tell me how .http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=325 and http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/

Comment: Ok I seem to have gotten it working through the method you posted Bargant. I have a specific sql login that I am using for this project and I added db_owner permissions under the sharepoint_adminconent and sharepoint_config databases under User Mapping. I did have a little bit of trouble after this with a different IIS Application Pool error but I refreshed the application pool and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution for the above issue is

Step1:Close the Visual Studio
Step2:ResetIIS
Step3:Open Run and Enter Services.msc, Restart the "**Windows Management Instrumentation**"   service
Step4: Recycle the Application pool in inetmgr.
Step5:Reopen the VisualStudio now deploy.

Hope it will help others.

Thanks & Regards
**Kishore Appini**

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced the same error, checking the following helped me:

1. Make sure the Web Application exists on SharePoint.
2. Make sure the site collection you are trying to deploy to, exists.
   This is the siteURL specified in your project's properties. To see
   this property, you have to press the F4 key after selecting the
   project in solution explorer (in Visual Studio).

In my case, I had not created the site collection and also the siteURL had a previous server mentioned in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the 'Site URL' correctly in the project properties.
click on your project name in the solution explorer and press F4 for properties.
Then check the Site URL.
The Site URL must be the same as Project Server URL.
example **http:// spsw001/pwa**

This solved the problem when I got this error message.

Answer (score 0):

This must be the solution for the scenarios: 
http://praveenbattula.blogspot.in/2013/07/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public URL for your collection which is a DNS entry that is pointing to your SharePoint server then what you need is an "Alternate Access Mapping".

1. Go to Central Admin > Application Management > Configure Alternate Access Mappings and create an internal URL for your public URL.
2. Set your project server url property to point to the newly created alternate access mapping and it should work.

Note: This is valid for SP 2013

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to missing database permissions. As mine was a DEV box, I just added my Windows account (=the account I was logged into the DEV server) to SQL Server as sysadmin.